# Ligatures not do not work in UILabel/NSAttributedString in iOS 6

Tags: cocoa, ios6, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am trying to turn on ligatures [(`NSLigatureAttributeName`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html) for an [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) displayed by a `UILabel`.

I am targeting iOS 6.1 and running in the iPad simulator.

My set of test words are:

- aeciospore
- coeliac
- halfheaded
- cliffhanging
- aufkommender
- snuffkin
- domineesbriefjes
- offtrack
- dahinraffte
- coffins

My [test code](https://gist.github.com/rjstelling/5501524) is simple, it loops through the list of words and display one in a `UILabel` using the `text` property:

```
self.normalLabel.text = words[i];
```

And the other using the `attributedText` property, after creating an `NSAttributedString` (see [Brandon Campbell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358724/89035) answer for more info on the value of `NSLigatureAttributeName`):

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{    NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:74.0],
                            NSLigatureAttributeName : @1, //@2 not supported in iOS
                            NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]};

self.attr.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:words[i] attributes:attrs];
```

As you can see I'm setting `NSLigatureAttributeName` to 2 (as an `NSNumber`). But this has no effect on the words:

[image: Ligatures do not working in UILabel using Attributed Strings]

[image: Ligatures do not working in UILabel using Attributed Strings]

I'm using the `systemFont` (Helvetica Neue), here is a debugger output:

```
(lldb) po self.attr.attributedText
$0 = 0x0719bc90 aeciospore{
    NSBackgroundColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x719cc80> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 74px";
    NSLigature = 1;
}
(lldb)
```

Comment: Are you using a font that supports ligatures?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the text or glyphs directly i Quartz?  The system font as shipped is likely optimized for standard system use, and may not include the support for ligatures.  If it does work, you can use a custom view for your label.  Most likely, however, you will need to choose a font explicitly, even if it appears to be the same as the system font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helvetica Neue that ships with iOS 6 [does not support ligatures](https://twitter.com/jamesdempsey/status/336496933357101058), using `Hoefler Text` solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs NSLigatureAttributeName 2 is unsupported on iOS.

> NSLigatureAttributeName 
>   The value of this attribute is an NSNumber
>   object containing an integer. Ligatures cause specific character
>   combinations to be rendered using a single custom glyph that
>   corresponds to those characters. The value 0 indicates no ligatures.
>   The value 1 indicates the use of the default ligatures. The value 2
>   indicates the use of all ligatures. The default value for this
>   attribute is 1. (Note that value 2 is unsupported on iOS.) Available
>   in iOS 6.0 and later.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I've tried with both `@1` value and `@YES` but it still does't work. I've updated the question to reference this.

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't help you solve your problem for most of your test words, but the documentation for [NSLigatureAttributeName](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html) states:

```
English text has no essential ligatures, and typically has only two standard ligatures,
those for “fi” and “fl”—all others being considered more advanced or fancy.
```

I'm surprised that you didn't see any difference with `coffins`, based on that information.